# Regarding basic properties of local homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology

Let $f \colon X_2 \to X_1$ and $g \colon Y_2 \to Y_1$ be local homeomorphisms and $h \colon X_1 \to Y_1$ a continuous map. For any $x_2 \in X_2$, is there always a choice of $U_2$ about $x_2$ such that the following holds?

> $f \colon U_2 \to f(U_2)$ is a homeomorphism, and $hf(U_2)$ is such that there is $V_2 \subset g^{-1}hf(U_2)$ such that $g \colon V_2 \to hf(U_2)$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Start by finding a suitable neighbourhood $W_2$ of some $y_2$ with $g(y_2) = h(f(x_2))$.

Comment: Can that always be found? Note that these spaces are arbitrary.

Comment: If $g$ is surjective, you can always find that. If $g$ is not surjective and $h(f(x_2)) \in \partial g(Y_2)$, there may not exist such sets.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A := g^{-1}( h(f(x_2)) $. if $A$ is nonempty, we choose $y_2 \in A$.
Let $U \subset Y_2$ is an neigborhood of $y_2$ such that $g|_U: U \rightarrow g(U) $ is a homeomorphism. We define $V := g(U)$ and next $U_0 := f^{-1}(h^{-1}( V ) )$. There is $U_1 \subset X_2$ an neigborhood of $x_2$ such that $f|_{U_1}: U_1 \rightarrow f(U_1) $ is a homeomorphism.
Finally we can define: $U_2 := U_0 \cap U_1$.